# Библиотека telegram API NodeJS

Tags: node.js, telegram

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста рабочую библиотеку для работы с клиентским API на NodeJS

(желательно ту, с которой вы работали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот с этой библиотекой работал: [telegram-mtproto](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto)

Только щас лучше поставить версию 2.2.x